# Nginx same location 2 blocks with diffrent proxy pass

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location, proxypass

Trying to configure nginx to have 2 proxy passes for the same location.
Example:

- `domain.com` to go to the homepage proxy
- `domain.com/user` to go to user profile proxy
  What i need to do:

What I tryed:

```
location = / { proxy_pass http://home_page; }

location ~ ^/(.+) { proxy_pass http://user_profile_page; }
```

If I go to `domain.com/` and `domain.com/username` it goes to the same proxy.

I have to mention that the config has also the `/auth` location block with exact match "="
that has `domain.com/auth`, `domain.com/auth/login`. This location block works as expected

```
location ^~ /auth { proxy_pass http://auth_page; }
```

Comment: Are any other locations defined in your server block? Or there are only this three?

Comment: At the moment those are the only locations but I will add locations like the auth path.

Comment: Then you don't need that regex location at all. You need `location = / { ... }` for root requests, `location /auth { ... }` for URIs starting with `/auth` and `location / { ... }` which will process everything else.

Comment: But I need 1 proxy pass for the root request and 1 proxy pass for the requests after the /
Eg 
domain.com - home upstream 
domain.com/[aZ-09] - User profile upstream

Comment: Made it work by adding the actual proxy passes, was testing with return 200.

 location = / {
        proxy_pass http://homepage_upstream;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+)$ {
     roxy_pass http://user_profile;
    }

Comment: I mean you don't need that regex location, `location / { ... }` will process **anything** that does not match other locations. For your current configuration it is just a performance penalty because of regex usage. Please, use [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) (especially backticks) when you include code fragments in your comments.